# Determine whether the light will reach certain points or not

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometric-optics

I've got an interesting question which goes like that: suppose we have a long cylindrical rod made of a transparent material (see illustration below). A point source $O$ which sits on rod's axis emits light in all directions. The light is partially reflected and partially refracted (i.e. goes to the air). The question is - which points will the light rays reach? (1) A only, (2) A and B only (3) All the four points (4) Not enough information

[image]

According to the book the right answer is (3), but I'm not so sure that this is correct - one the one hand, the light is emitted in all possible directions but on the other hand, my friend thinks there could be a total internal reflection at some point. In both cases there's no strict proof for either answer.

By the way, there's no information about positions, indices of refractions and so on.

Comment: You friend is right thinking about the total internal reflection. Now, check at which angle the light exits the rod when the total internal reflection is just about to happen (i.e. the incidence angle increases)

Comment: Mind you, some points will be dimly illuminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cross section of the rod:

[image: Refraction]

Snell's law tells us that the angle $r$ is given by:

$$ \sin r = n \sin i $$

where $n$ is the refractive index of the rod ($n \gt 1$). No matter how far down the rod $D$ is there will be a value for $i$ that allows the light to reach $D$. The total internal reflection angle is the limiting value for $i$ as the distance to $D$ goes to infinity and $r \rightarrow \pi/2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But he argues that there's no guarantee that if $D$ is far away from the rod the light ray will necessarily hit the point $O$ (the light ray path is reversible, so I'm actually talking about hitting D). In other words, as $r$ approaches $\pi/2$ it will still refract, but nobody promises it will pass $O$. Maybe $O$ is to the left of the point you've made in your illustration, and if $i$ at that time reaches its critical value than the ray may never actually reach $O$.

Comment: The thing is that the equation I've written down **guarantees** that there is **always** a light ray from O that will reach D. If your friend can provide a proof showing I'm wrong I would be interested to see it.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a point where we have total internal reflection, in that case the light trying to leave the rod at that particular 'critical angle' will be totally reflected.  So you are saying if this is the case, then there will be a point outside the rod where the light doesn't reach?

This wouldn't be the case, the light will be partially reflected from the both sides of the rod many times meaning that there will be more than one way for the light to reach each point outside the rod.

So if point A, B, C or D was at a position where the light coming straight from the source was totally internally reflected and couldn't reach the point, there would still be ways for light which had been partially reflected from the other side of the rod to reach it.

Also, if the light is not monochromatic the different frequencies will be refracted by different amounts and we wouldn't require the light to have been partially reflected from the other side of the rod at all.  The refraction would provide many other routes for the light to travel to each point outside the rod.